# filtering a dataframe, present rows depending on the value of certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following type of dataframe and I want to leave only rows where columns that are named 'Model' are equal to 'BUY' or 'SELL'

Input:

```
          Date Ticker IssuerTier     Action  ... ModelG1 ModelG2  ModelG3  ModelG4
0   2020-05-28   AAPL       gold       None  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND
1   2020-05-28   ABBV       gold  reiterate  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND
2   2020-05-28   ABMD   standard       None  ...   STAND   STAND    SELL     STAND
3   2020-05-28   ACAD       gold       None  ...   BUY     STAND    STAND    STAND
4   2020-05-28   ADSK   standard       None  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND
..         ...    ...        ...        ...  ...     ...     ...      ...      ...
130 2020-05-28    WEX       gold       None  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND
131 2020-05-28   WYNN       gold       None  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND
132 2020-05-28    ZEN       gold       None  ...   BUY     STAND    STAND    STAND
133 2020-05-28    ZEN       gold  reiterate  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND
134 2020-05-28    ZEN     silver       None  ...   STAND   STAND    STAND    STAND

[135 rows x 58 columns]
```

Output:

```
          Date Ticker IssuerTier     Action  ... ModelG1 ModelG2  ModelG3  ModelG4


2   2020-05-28   ABMD   standard       None  ...   STAND   STAND    SELL     STAND
3   2020-05-28   ACAD       gold       None  ...   BUY     STAND    STAND    STAND
132 2020-05-28    ZEN       gold       None  ...   BUY     STAND    STAND    STAND
```

I tried using the following masks but I've gotten NaNs on all my dataframe for some reason:

```
mask1 = signals.loc[:, 'ModelA1':] == 'BUY'
mask2 = signals.loc[:, 'ModelA1':] == 'SELL'
signals = signals[mask1 & mask2]
```

The model columns go from A1, A2, A3, A4... to G1, G2, G3, G4.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model_cols = (cols for cols in signals.columns if cols.startswith("Model"))
mask = signals[model_cols].apply(lambda s: "BUY" in s.values or "SELL" in s.values, axis=1)
signals = signals[mask]
```

We first get the "model" columns, then generate mask with your condition and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
cols_to_check = list(filter(lambda col : col.startswith('Model'), df.columns))

def should_allow(row):
    return all(map(lambda col : row[col] in ('BUY', 'SELL'), cols_to_check))

df = df[df.apply(should_allow, axis=1)]
print(df)
```